# IE javascript troubles

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have site which was mainly designed for full flash with SWFAddress, therefore all links end up with hash "#" sign (eg.: www.site.com/#/folder/image.jpg).

I want to switch flash to full HTML and don't make any of the links dead (as I left a lot of links around the web), so I created htaccess file to control the incomming requests.
The problem was with the hash "#" sign because it couldn't be handled by htaccess file. I made a piece of javascript code on top of my first index.php.

So, before I load any controller, the index.php file starts with javascript to remove hash sign and redirect back to the site without "#" i n url :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var link = location.href;
m = removeHash(link);

if (link != m) { 
    document.location.href = m;
}

function removeHash(l) {
    var unhashedUrl = l;
    if (l.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        var url_pieces = l.split('/');
        var request = url_pieces[url_pieces.length-1];
        if(request.indexOf("#") == -1 && request.toLowerCase().indexOf(".jpg") > -1){
            unhashedUrl = l.replace('#', "gallery");
        }else{
            unhashedUrl = l.replace('#/', "");
        }
    }
    return unhashedUrl;
}

</script>
```

Then all php stuff begins...

Chrome, firefox, Opera, Safari, mobile browsers... They all works flawlessly. But again the IE (tested IE8 and IE9) end up crazy. It looks like IE won't fire any JS later on. Of course when I remove JS from index controller IE works good too.

Any advice how should I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the IE console when you load the page? Perhaps a method in the `removeHash` function is not supported

Comment: agreed. Use the IE dev tools (F12) to look for any errors that are generated.

Comment: No errors in IE console. I've updted the javascript code in my question. The problems seems to be in the head. When I add `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <head>` before any JS to main index.php, then IE works, but I can't do this as I don't know what language is the site ("en" or "fr") before I check it in PHP (but first I need to remove hash in JS)...

Comment: Well, yes, that would do it -- if you didn't have a doctype, then IE would go into quirks mode, which means it would be lacking a lot of standard features, so it would not be a surprise if any JS code fails. So you definitely should always include the basic doctype/html/head code. Anyway, since this page just redirects to another page, why do you even need to specify the `lang=''` at all; just do `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...` Problem solved.

Comment: I don't know really if it holds the "#" hash tag, I need to check it first, so I need to fire JS anyway... It redirect back to the same index.php but without "#". As for the Errors in Console: Yes indeed, there's an error. It shows error in placeholder.js, but when I click it, it points to the first <script> tag (which is im my question) `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
placeholder.js, row 1 Sign 1`.

Comment: Did you try adding, `console.log`s/`alert`s after every relevant line outputing relevant infos?